# To run curl command on postman getting error as Error while importing Curl: arg.startsWith is not a function

Tags: postman, docker-command, curl-commandline

I have a curl link which is successfully run with terminal but i want to convert it as a `POSTMAN` request where link is,

```
curl -v --silent -H "Accept: application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json" -X GET -u <registry-user>:<registry-password> https://sc-docker-registry.eic.fullstream.ai/v2/<image-name>/manifests/<tag> 2>&1 --insecure  | grep Docker-Content-Digest | awk '{print ($3)}'
```

I have set header and auth but unable to set `2>&1 --insecure  | grep Docker-Content-Digest | awk '{print ($3)}'`

Where do I set `2>&1 --insecure  | grep Docker-Content-Digest | awk '{print ($3)}'` command in postman

Answer (score 34):

I had the issue when using *"Copy all as cURL (bash)"* instead of just *"Copy as cURL (bash)"*.

A few concatenated curl commands were copied. And Postman's import didn't like that.

[image: "Copy all as cURL (bash)" vs "Copy as cURL (bash)"]

Comment: I dont have that option. Just "Copy as cURL".

Answer (score 27):

I had the same issue but chrome now gives you the option to copy curl as `(bash)` or `(cmd)`. I had the issue when using copy as `cmd` but worked when I used copy as `bash`

Answer (score 14):

I had the same error and I think it's unrelated to the pipeline arguments you sent at the end of the curl. Enclosing url part into double quotes helped with my case. Looks like its a bug in [curl-to-postman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/curl-to-postman) library

Answer (score 10):

Personally for me the problem was a semicolon at the end of the cURL request. Try to remove all the noise you can until you find what sort of character is making postman have that error

```
curl 'http://catalog.data.gov/api/3/' \
  -H 'authority: 1fzqk3npw4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com' \
  -H 'accept: */*' \
  -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.111 Safari/537.36' \  
  --compressed ;
```

**Remove the semicolon at the end**

Answer (score 2):

I removed all the single quotes to **Double quotes** and it worked !!!

Not Working CURL

```
curl --location --request POST 'http://localhost/data/?type=MOBILE&value=77700023656' \
--header 'accept: */*'
```

WORKING CURL (changed single quotes --> double quotes)

```
curl --location --request POST "http://localhost/data/?type=MOBILE&value=77700023656" \
--header "accept: */*"
```

Answer (score 1):

remove character \ in the end of all lines
for who is using vscode, replace all by regex
[image: replace all by regex]