# Getting Error while trying to import a Curl request in Postman

Tags: curl, postman

Below is the snapshot comprising the Curl request which I am trying to import. How can this be done?

[image: Snapshot of Postman with curl request]

[image: Snapshot of error coming in Postman]

Comment: Hey possible duplication of this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006009/to-run-curl-command-on-postman-getting-error-as-error-while-importing-curl-arg

Comment: please paste the curl command as string also

Comment: Does this answer your question? [To run curl command on postman getting error as Error while importing Curl: arg.startsWith is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61006009/to-run-curl-command-on-postman-getting-error-as-error-while-importing-curl-arg)